# Trouble with securing a Tomcat/Axis2 web service via SSL

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, ssl, apache-axis

I have successfully built a working web service, client, and .jsp-driven UI. I did this with Eclipse, Axis2, Tomcat 7, and Java 7.

The basic flow is that the user visits the .jsp and submits a form with input data. The JSP forwards the "request" object to the Java client. The Java client consumes the web service and submits the user input. The service connects to a SQL Server database via JDBC to retrieve information, which is displayed back to the user.

This all works perfectly over HTTP, but now I want to secure the process, and this is where I'm running into problems. I'm able to create a cert and get Tomcat to use it. I can connect to the web UI via HTTPS and submit the form and get data back just fine. The problem is that this is only securing the front-end. The web service client code is still connecting to the service via HTTP in the background.

According to [this page](http://shivendra-tripathi.blogspot.com/2010/11/enabling-ssl-for-axis2-service-and.html), all I really need to do to enable my service for connections via SSL is to update the axis2.xml file and include a new "transportReceiver" node for HTTPS. I did that and regenerated my client code to use the secure endpoint. It doesn't work.

I have configured Tomcat to listen on ports 8081 for http and 8443 for https. But after changing axis2.xml to match, and starting up Tomcat, I get the following:

> [INFO] Listening on port 8443  [ERROR] Terminating connection
>   listener
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.http.server.DefaultConnectionListener@16d60567
>   after 10retries in 0 seconds.  java.net.BindException: Address already
>   in use: JVM_Bind  at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native
>   Method)  at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Unknown
>   Source)  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.net.ServerSocket.(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.net.ServerSocket.(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.apache.axis2.transport.http.server.DefaultConnectionListener.run(DefaultConnectionListener.java:80)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) 
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) 
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

I have tried changing the port number in axis2.xml (for example, to 8445), and that sort of works. The server is able to start cleanly, but eventually, the same errors start showing up. For example, when I retrieve the WSDL, I see the error via the console (though the WSDL does show up). Also, if I try to actually use the service when on port 8445, I get the following error:

> org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Connection has been shutdown:
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext
>   connection?

I can only assume this is because Tomcat is configured to handle HTTPS on 8443, not 8445, but I honestly don't know.

If I leave the port as 8443 and ignore the errors at startup, I get the following message when I connect to the service:

> org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Connection has been shutdown:
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

I followed [these steps](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=210) to try to get it to recognize my certificate, but when importing it into my JRE7 keystore, I get the following:

> keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Certificate reply and certificate
>   in keystore are identical

Basically, that cert is already there. Which makes sense, because it's the one that Tomcat is already using successfully.

So, I'm pretty clueless at this point. I'm really not sure what I'm supposed to be doing. Any general guidance, or a link to a step-by-step how-to would be really helpful.

But for a specific question... What, exactly, am I doing when I set the transportReceiver nodes in axis2.xml? Am I telling it what ports Tomcat is running on and that it should use, or does Axis2 have its own servers that will start on those ports? It seems to be the latter, but that doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to configure the servlet transport is described in the [Axis2 documentation](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/http-transport.html). The symptoms you are describing suggest that you have a transportReceiver that refers to org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SimpleHTTPServer. Please also make sure that you use a recent version of Axis2 (1.5.6 or 1.6.1).

Comment: Yes, that was it!  I changed the transportReceiver entries to use AxisServletListener, and that resolved the port issues.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

See Andreas's response for the port issue.  As for the certificate issue, it was a misunderstanding on my part over the distinction between a keystore and truststore.  The JVM defaults to using JAVA_HOME\lib\security\cacerts as its trust store, rather than the USER_HOME\.keystore file.  Once I imported my certificate there, the errors went away.

I was also able to resolve the certificate problems by explicity setting the trust store to be the key store file, via code.  I did this before importing the certificate into the cacerts store.  It goes in the client code, right before invoking the service:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","C:\\path\\to\\.keystore");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","password");
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the way to connect to HTTPS is using jax-ws

```
E:\WSDL>wsimport -keep -p com.mypack.webservice https://domain:port/ws/MyService?wsdl
```

This will generate package structure under the wsdl folder. Use it.

Now all you have to do is put trust store in `run.bat` or use `System` class to set property.

It will work fine.